# Agregar valor a un elemento de Combobox y luego poder guardar ese dato en un archivo .txt

Tags: c#, io

Como están? Estoy aprendiendo C# mediante Visual Studio y estoy haciendo un programa del tipo ABM donde tengo que cargar las ventas de fin de mes de unos vendedores, esto lo tengo que guardar en un archivo .txt usando las librerias de System.IO. Mi idea era que dentro del combox, cada nombre del producto tenga un valor al que pueda utilizar para hacer cuentas y demases. Acá les dejo una imagen del programa y el código debajo!: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
introducir el código aquí

{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bttn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream archivo = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Cursos.txt", FileMode.Append);
        StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(archivo);

        string registro;
        registro = txt_seller.Text + ";" + cbx_curso.Text + ";" + txt_inscriptos.Text + ";" + txt_comision.Text;
        escritor.WriteLine(registro);

        escritor.Close();
        archivo.Close();

        Listar();

    }
    void Listar()
    {
        lstListado.Items.Clear();

        FileStream archivo = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Cursos.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader lector = new StreamReader(archivo);

        string registro;

        while (lector.Peek() != -1) 
        {
            registro = lector.ReadLine();
            lstListado.Items.Add(registro);
        }

        lector.Close();
        archivo.Close();

        txt_inscriptos.Clear();
        txt_comision.Clear();

    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Listar();

        
    }


    private void bttn_del_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream archivo = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Cursos.txt", FileMode.Open);
        FileStream archivoAux = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/CursosAux.txt", FileMode.Create);

        StreamReader lector = new StreamReader(archivo);
        StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(archivoAux);

        string registro;
        string[] vector;
        

        while (lector.Peek() != -1)
        {
            registro = lector.ReadLine();
            vector = registro.Split(';');

            if (txt_inscriptos.Text != vector[1])
            {
                escritor.WriteLine(registro);
            }
        }
        

        lector.Close();
        escritor.Close();
        archivo.Close();
        archivoAux.Close();

        File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Cursos.txt");
        File.Move(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/CursosAux.txt", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Cursos.txt");

        Listar();
    }

    private void lstListado_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string registro;
        registro = lstListado.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string[] vector;
        vector = registro.Split(';');
        cbx_curso.Text = vector[0]; 
        txt_inscriptos.Text = vector[1];
        txt_comision.Text = vector[2];
        txt_seller.Text = vector[3];    
    }
}
```

}

Necesitaría saber como puedo poner un valor a cada "Curso" para despues poder sumar ese precio dependiendo la cantidad de alumnos inscriptos y etc, me estoy mareando y no puedo encontrar solucion

Answer (score 0):

C# es un lenguaje orientado a Objetos no a texto. Por lo que debes ocupar clases.

Existen muchas formas de hacer programación en C#, muchas buenas y muchas malas. Como he visto repetidamente que muchos se decantan por la segunda forma, voy a tratar de explicar cómo se debería hacer. El concepto clave es el "Binding" (por si quieres investigar sobre ello)

Te dejo una demo para que veas como se puede hacer

```js
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingList<Curso> Cursos;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            
        Cursos = GetCursos();

        comboBox1.DataSource = Cursos;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
           
    }

    public Curso GetSelected() => (Curso)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => GuardarCursos();
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Cursos.Remove(GetSelected());


    private BindingList<Curso> GetCursos()
    {
        using (FileStream archivo = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Cursos.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (StreamReader lector = new StreamReader(archivo))
            {
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BindingList<Curso>>(lector.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }

    private void GuardarCursos()
    {
        using (FileStream archivo = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Cursos.txt", FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(archivo))
            {
                escritor.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Cursos));
            }
        } 
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = GetSelected().Inscritos.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = GetSelected().Valor.ToString();
    }

}

public class Alumnos
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string NombreComplet { get => $"{Nombre} {Apellido}"; }
}

public class Curso
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<Alumnos> Alumnos { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public int Inscritos { get => Alumnos?.Count ?? 0; }
}
```

**Explicación:**

1.- Creamos 2 clases Curso y Alumnos, teniendo en cuenta que un Curso puede tener una lista de alumnos (list Alumnos)

2.- Creamos los componentes

- comboBox1 para mostrar el listado de cursos
- textBox1 Textbox que indica la cantidad de inscritos en el curso seleccionado
- textBox2 Textbox que indica el valor del curso seleccionado
- button1 botón para guardar los curos en un TXT
- button2 remueve el curso seleccionado

3.- Guardar y leer TXT
Vamos a guardar un TXT pero en formato JSON, así podemos serializar y deserializar rápidamente. Esto es convertir el json en objeto y un objeto en JSON. Estas funciones son:

- GetCursos() Lee el TXT y lo convierte a una lista de Objetos del tipo Curso
- GuardarCursos() Toma una lista de Cursos, la convierte en JSON y lo guarda en el text

**Ahora viene lo importante**

```
private BindingList<Curso> Cursos;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    Cursos = GetCursos();
    comboBox1.DataSource = Cursos;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
           
}
public Curso GetSelected() => (Curso)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

- Arriba tenemos una lista de cursos como variable global
- Cursos = GetCursos(); Setea esa lista con los valores guardados del JSON
- Luego al combobox le decimos que su DataSource (fuente de datos) es la lista. Esto provoca lo siguiente:

  - El componente queda enlazado a la lista, NO una copia si no la misma lista.
  - La lista es del tipo `BindingList` que es un tipo especial de listas. Además de guardar elementos, AVISA de cambios en la lista. Entonces todos lo que hagas en la lista se actualiza en el Componente de forma automática, por ejemplo el button2 que remueve un elemento se tiene Cursos.Remove(GetSelected()), ahí quitamos un elemento de la lista y el comobobox refleja ese cambio inmediatamente sin haber tenido que actualizarlo
- Luego tenemos comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre"; Fíjate que el combobox está enlazado a una lista de Cursos, pero como sabe el combobox que texto mostrar?? Con esto le decimos que muestre la propiedad "Nombre"
- Finalmente la función  Curso GetSelected() => (Curso)comboBox1.SelectedItem esta función devuelve un Item selecciando, Pero que es un Item??? Es un Curso. Porque aunque se muestre "Nombre" como texto en el combobox, lo que almacena son Cursos. Entonces GetSelected() te devolverá siempre el Curso que está seleccionado en el momento, con lo cual tu podrás realizar operaciones.

**Posible mejoras:**

Te recominedo que:

1. Agregues un DataGridView para mostrar los Alumnos del cursos. El DataGridView, también tiene una propiedad "DataSource" es decir tienes que usar la misma lógica que el combobox
2. Investiga sobre INotifyPropertyChanged. Cuando realizamos un cambio en una BindingList se Notifica a los componentes bindiados que hay un cambio. Pero qué pasa si existe una modificación en una propiedad del objeto guardado?? No se notifica, para ello está el INotifyPropertyChanged. Y de qué sirve?? Por ejemplo tú tienes 3 propiedades

- Valor
- Cantidad
- Total = Valor * Cantidad

Y editas Valor, en la paantalla no veras actualizado el Total a menos que ocupes INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Voy a implementar todo lo que me explicaste! Tenes razon, es de objetos y no de texto, pequeño error ajaja. Te agradezco muchisimo la data y ayuda! Saludos!